# `return` не выполняется, а выполняется `except`

Tags: python, request, условия

```
def getHtml(url, n, ip):
    try:
        r = requests.get(url, proxies={"https": ip[n]})
        if len(r.text) > 100000:
            return r.text
    except:
        n +=1
        getHtml(url, n, ip)
```

**Когда срабатывает условие - `if len(r.text) > 100000: return r.text`,
`return` не выполняется, а выполняется `except`.**

Comment: Или уберите try-except, или запихните raise, чтобы увидеть, какая именно ошибка случилась

Answer (score 2):

Вы рекурсивно вызываете вашу функцию `getHtml()`. Вместо того просто проходите ваш список `ip` в цикле:

```
def getHtml(url, n, ip):
    for proxy in ip:
        try:
            r = requests.get(url, proxies={"https": proxy})
            if len(r.text) > 100000:
                return r.text
            else
                return    # None или что-то другое
        except:
            continue      # продолщать с последующим proxy
```

Answer (score 0):

Очевидно какая-то ошибка происходит в `return r.text`. Вы бы прописали в `except` какое исключение ожидаете поймать. Остальные сами вылезут

Comment: не `return r.text`, а `len(r.text)`

Comment: Позвольте уточнить почему Вы так решили? У len() есть какие-то ограничения на выводимые значения?